# Dockerized Next.js is out of memory (OOM: code 137), but numbers don't add to max memory

Tags: node.js, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, next.js

We are running our app in docker images in a kubernetes cluster. Every pod has the memory limit of 512Mb. Our app is restarting around every 2.5 half days with OOM error even though seemingly it didn't reach the limit (see screenshot).

[image: Grafana dashboard]

As you can see on 29th of September around 17:30 the pod restarted.

Adding to my confusion is the **sawtooth usage of memory**: it seems that time to time memory consumption goes very low, but the next time it *"starts from where the one before ended"*.

I have not set the memory limit of `node` yet, since I'm not exactly sure it would help.

**How can I debug this scenario?**

**How can I make sense of these graphs?**

I have also tried clicking around in the project while I'm run Chrome profiler, but I don't see any new objects allocated between snapshots.

[image: Chrome profiler snapshots]

Comment: It definitely looks like a memory leak, spikes being memory freed after batch of requests served but the general pattern is that it keeps growing which it shouldn't assuming request rates stay same.

Comment: I can confirm that the increase doesn't match actual traffic to the site.